# MRTK and Vuforia on Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, mrtk

Looking to make an app for Hololens (1st gen) with Vuforia and MRTK.
The intent is to have several 3D models be displayed as holograms based on different vumarks.
Want to use MRTK to rotate the models using hand gestures and resize them as well.

Question is about MRTK vs holotoolkit. Which one should I be using. Does one have more features than the other? I understand that MRTK is newer and
it used to be known as holotoolkit. Wondering if any features were removed from holotoolkit before it changed to MRTK?

Which one between MRTK and holotoolkit works better with the Vuforia engine?

Also, I want to rotate the 3D models along the x axis. Followed this tutorial involving a pre-built sample https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/holograms-211, where user can rotate model on y axis using hand axis. I can't seem to figure out how to do rotation on the x axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MRTKv2 be always recommended for accelerating cross-platform MR app development in Unity.
It re-implements most of the features in HTK and is going to add new functions based on feedback from the developer community. This porting guide shows the difference between they:[HTKToMRTKPortingGuide](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/HTKToMRTKPortingGuide.html?q=htk)

For how to make Vuforia work with the MRTK, there is a closed issue that show a workaround to do it: [What's the current status of using Vuforia with the MR Toolkit? #1461](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/1461)

For how to do a rotation on the x-axis, the line `transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, -1 * rotationFactor, 0));` in the GestureAction.cs from the tutorial is the [key point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/tutorials/holograms-211#instructions-4). The [`Transform.Rotate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html) method can rotate GameObjects in a variety of ways and it takes a Vector3 argument that specified the Euler angle in 3 vectors for x, y, and z. So you can do it by exchanging the parameter order of Vector3 instance, such as  `transform.Rotate(new Vector3(-1 * rotationFactor,0 , 0));`